# calculate relative ranking for every possible timeframe (memory efficient)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, memory-management

I want to know how well a specific footballer (player "P1" for example) performed compared all others (sum of goals). I have a data.frame of goals per year per footballer. The timeframe for my result is not static but all possible timeframes are interesting to know in which years a player had a good or bad performance.

For 10 years are are 10*10/2 possible timeframes. The following plot shows that between 2003 and 2008 there were n=10 players in the database and the player we are looking at was the best of all with 85 goals in total:

---

[image: example matrix for 10 years]

---

Calculating the result is not a problem, but instead of yearly data I'd like to switch to monthly data (120*120/2 timeframes in 10 years). The result itself is quite small. But for 5000 footballers or even 20000 players my approach to get to the result uses too much memory for 32-bit-environments (problem is the dplyr **inner_join**):

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb

Is there a more "clever" way to compute the relative rank of a player for each timeframe? (memory-wise)

```R
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)

# config example data
analyse_for_player <- "P1"
number_of_players <- 1000 # 1k works, 10k would be a problem
number_of_years <- 120 # still named "years", will be months later

# generate example data
player <- rep(paste0("P", seq(1, number_of_players)), rep(c(number_of_years), number_of_players))
date <- rep(seq(as.Date("1900/12/31"), by = "years", length.out = number_of_years), number_of_players)
goals <- round(runif(n = number_of_players * number_of_years, min = 0, max = 20), 0)

df <- data.frame(player, date, goals)

df <- df %>%
  # self join to get every possible from-to-combination
  inner_join(df, "player", suffix = c(".from", ".to"), relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  # only need triangle = 1 half of square
  filter(date.to >= date.from) %>%
  group_by(player, date.from) %>%
  arrange(date.to) %>%
  # important: if there was a gap (player didn't play each year), don't use it for calculations
  filter(year(date.to) - year(date.from) == row_number() - 1) %>%
  mutate(goalsum = cumsum(goals.to)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(date.from, date.to) %>%
  mutate(RANK_PCT = percent_rank(goalsum), n_players = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(player == analyse_for_player) %>%
  select(player, date.from, date.to, goalsum, RANK_PCT, n_players)

plot_ly(
  x = df$date.from, y = df$date.to, z = df$RANK_PCT, text = paste0(
    "From: ",
    df$date.from, "\n", "To: ", df$date.to, "\n", "goals: ", df$goalsum,
    "\n", "n: ", df$n_players, "\n", "rank (pct): ", df$RANK_PCT * 100, "\n"
  ), type = "heatmap",
  hoverinfo = "text"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `data.table`.
I've simply converted your code to the data.table equivalent, though I'm sure there's a more efficient method more broadly speaking.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
# I picked this seed using as.integer(Sys.time())
set.seed(1681148852) # Avoid small seed sizes

# config example data
analyse_for_player <- "P1"
number_of_players <- 1000 # 1k works, 10k would be a problem
number_of_years <- 120 # still named "years", will be months later

# generate example data
player <- rep(paste0("P", seq(1, number_of_players)), rep(c(number_of_years), number_of_players))
date <- rep(seq(as.Date("1900/12/31"), by = "years", length.out = number_of_years), number_of_players)
goals <- round(runif(n = number_of_players * number_of_years, min = 0, max = 20), 0)

df <- data.table(player, date, goals)

df <- merge(df, df,
  all.x = TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE, by = "player",
  suffixes = c(".from", ".to")
)
gc() # Clear memory immediately
#>            used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
#> Ncells  1047406  56.0    2107208 112.6  1416990  75.7
#> Vcells 74136296 565.7  110202800 840.8 97893363 746.9
df <- df[date.to >= date.from]
df[, grp := .GRP, by = c("player", "date.from")]
setkeyv(df, cols = "grp")
df[, rowid := seq_len(.N), by = "grp"]
setorderv(df, cols = "date.to", na.last = TRUE)
df <- df[year(date.to) - year(date.from) == rowid - 1]
df[, goalsum := cumsum(goals.to), by = "grp"]
df[, RANK_PCT := percent_rank(goalsum), by = "grp"]
df[, n_players := .N, by = "grp"]
df <- df[player == analyse_for_player]
df <- df[, .SD, .SDcols = c("player", "date.from", "date.to", "goalsum", "RANK_PCT", "n_players")]
p <- plot_ly(
  x = df$date.from, y = df$date.to, z = df$RANK_PCT, text = paste0(
    "From: ",
    df$date.from, "\n", "To: ", df$date.to, "\n", "goals: ", df$goalsum,
    "\n", "n: ", df$n_players, "\n", "rank (pct): ", df$RANK_PCT * 100, "\n"
  ), type = "heatmap",
  hoverinfo = "text"
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>